# Gitlab CI/CD: Changing/setting project versions based on branch name in pom.xml files

Tags: java, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I started working with gitlab CI/CD, but previously was working with Jenkins.

In Jenkins we had some pipelines/groovy scripts that automatically detected and changed project.version in pom.xml file depends on the branch name, so If e.g. I’d pushed to branch called project/task-1 and pom.xml contains

```
<version>dev-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

then dev-SNAPSHOT was automatically changed to task-1-SNAPSHOT.

And the same with release branches, If we pushed to release/0.0.1, the project.version during the build changed incrementing the tag version during each build, so If it was build number 4 the final project.version was 0.0.1.4 etc.

Right now in gitlab CI/CD we must manually increment project.version before every build. I’d searched the internet and unfortunately didn’t find anything about automating this process in Gitlab CI.

So I would like to ask, is it possible to do something like this with Gitlab?

If so, can someone give an examples how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For including the branch name in version:

Use a variable in your `<version>` value:

```
<version>${branch}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Then in your ci script, run maven with arguments:

```
./mvnw -Dbranch=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH} clean install/package/deploy/etc
```

You may need to use different [predefined CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) depending on whether a tag or branch was pushed (or if it was a merge request event etc.)

You can put a sensible default in your pom.xml's properties section

```
<properties>
    <branch>local</branch>
</properties>
```

This will be used if no value is provided when building.

Comment: Is it possibile to do the same with release branches?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "Release branches" are not any different from any other branches.

Comment: I mean, the solution you wrote will work If I will push to branch like "develop" or "task-1" without any prefix. What If I want to push to branch called "release/23.0" and create the project build(with tag) in version 23.0.1? Then I don't want the version to be 23.0-SNAPSHOT, but 23.0.1 or 23.0.2 etc.